# How to insert all keys from nested dict to new nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am writing test automation and have to insert all values from my variable into new dictionary but for some reason it always takes just the last. What could be the reason?

Variable with nested dictionary:

```
{'~Manager~': {"operatorId": 'in the selection list'},
 'Candidate': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'not in the selection list'},
  ...
 'Description': {"operatorId": 'is empty'}}
```

```
def _prepare_filters_json(self, pipeline: str, filter_to_add: dict):
    new_filter = {"type": 'CONDITION', "id": 'any_id', "field": 'null',
                  "operatorId": 'null'}
    source_fields = self.ssi_get_filter_source_fields(pipeline).json_path("$.data")
    filters = self._get_filters(pipeline)
    for source_field in source_fields:
        for key in filter_to_add.keys():
            if key == source_field["descriptor"]:
                new_filter["field"] = source_field
    return self._prepare_json(pipelineId=pipeline, filter=filters)
```

`source_fields` returns list of dictionaries. If the value from that list is `==` to dict.keys in my variable it should update my `new_filter`.

Actual result:

```
{'field': {'descriptor': 'Description',
           'id': 'edee9a85b3fb4cb69b993139fc14ce46',
           'returnType': 'Text'},
 'id': 'any_id',
 'operatorId': 'null',
 'type': 'CONDITION'}
```

Expected result:

```
{'field': {'descriptor': '~Manager~',
           'id': 'edee9a85b3fb4cb69b993139fc123451',
           'returnType': 'Text'},
'field': {'descriptor': 'Candidate',
           'id': 'edee9a85b3fb4cb69b993139fc141111',
           'returnType': 'Text'},
'field': {'descriptor': 'Description',
           'id': 'edee9a85b3fb4cb69b993139fc14ce46',
           'returnType': 'Text'},
 'id': 'any_id',
 'operatorId': 'null',
 'type': 'CONDITION'}
```

Comment: "Expected result:" This result cannot be created by *any* code. A dict's keys are unique. That's why key lookup can work deterministically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a mistake and now it works as expected.

```
def _prepare_filters_json(self, pipeline: str, filter_to_add: dict):
    new_filter = {"type": 'CONDITION', "id": 'any_id', "field": 'null',
                  "operatorId": 'null'}
    source_fields = self.ssi_get_filter_source_fields(pipeline).json_path("$.data")
    filters = self._get_filters(pipeline)
    for key in filter_to_add.keys():
        for source_field in source_fields:
          if source_field["descriptor"] == key:
            new_filter["field"] = source_field
            filters["children"].append(dict(new_filter))
    return self._prepare_json(pipelineId=pipeline, filter=filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, however I think what you want is a list of fields moved into your new_filter dictionary. In that case I would create a fields-list inside your new_filter dict and append the objects to this list, so your output would look something like this:

```
{'fields': [{'descriptor': '~Manager~',
           'id': 'edee9a85b3fb4cb69b993139fc123451',
           'returnType': 'Text'},
{'descriptor': 'Candidate',
           'id': 'edee9a85b3fb4cb69b993139fc141111',
           'returnType': 'Text'},
{'descriptor': 'Description',
           'id': 'edee9a85b3fb4cb69b993139fc14ce46',
           'returnType': 'Text'}],
 'id': 'any_id',
 'operatorId': 'null',
 'type': 'CONDITION'}
```

This could be achieved by doing something along the lines of the below:

```
def _prepare_filters_json(self, pipeline: str, filter_to_add: dict):
  new_filter = {"type": 'CONDITION', "id": 'any_id', "fields": [], "operatorId": 'null'}
  source_fields = self.ssi_get_filter_source_fields(pipeline).json_path("$.data")
  filters = self._get_filters(pipeline)
  for source_field in source_fields:
    for key in filter_to_add.keys():
      if key == source_field["descriptor"]:
        new_filter["fields"].append(source_field)
  return self._prepare_json(pipelineId=pipeline, filter=filters)
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I am testing BE and body should look like in Expected result. And you cannot append to a string.

Comment: The Expected result is not possible, as you have 3 keys called field in a single dict. Keys in a dict have to be unique. I turned fields into a list (Not a string) in the suggested code in order to circumvent the issue of using 3 keys with the same name and instead having a list you can append objects to. It does however seem I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have duplicates with the same key as you mention inside a dictionary in Python.

I think you'd rather have a list with all the individual dicts instead of nested in a dict.

You can do some tricky stuff like described [here](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3934_Multiple-identical-keys-in-a-Python-dict-yes-you-can-.html).

Comment: But I don't want to have duplicates. I want to take the 1st key:value - *{'~Manager~': {"operatorId": 'in the selection list'}}* and execute my code, add it to field in new_dictionary. Then take the second key:value *{'Candidate':{"AND":"", "operatorId": 'not in the selection list'}* and again execute my code by adding another field to new_dict.